# I registered my Stack Overflow account and lost all my privileges!

Tags: support, stack-overflow, merge-accounts

Just wondering if its normal that I lost all my Stack Overflow privileges and badges when I registered my account.  I can no longer see any of the questions I was following either.

Comment: meta.stackoverflow.com would be more appropriate to discuss the mechanics of the site

Answer (score 8):

I merged your accounts.  With my awesomeness.  Enjoy.

Comment: Awesome! Mark this as status-completed and we're good to go. ♪

Comment: Truly, your awesomeness engenders awe.

Answer (score 3):

No, normally you retain everything when registering an unregistered account. I still remember having that myself, actually.

I think you may have registered a new account rather than the account you had while unregistered. Your account that is newly registered has only been a member since yesterday. Assumedly, by the surprise of content loss, you had more than a day's worth of contributions accumulated.

There should probably still be an unregistered account that holds all of your old questions, badges, and reputation. I can't find it, but a Stack Overflow moderator will be able to search through the list of unregistered users and possibly find it. Or, if you already can find your old account via browsing history, I'd just add the information in a flag for moderator attention. They can then merge the unregistered account with your new registered account, which will get you back your badges and privileges and favorited questions.